# api/v1/register:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, backend, cloudinary

when i try to  default register a new user  then i can't register it on website ,and it shows internal server error in  and failed to load resource error in console .

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFa17.png)[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrSB2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWlKT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMAnc.png) please help ...


I tried everything ,double checked the codes ,still could solve the error,
```

I think the the fault lies somewhere in the backend integration with cloudinary  I have shared the  usermodel and usercontroller.

```
edit 1:
user model 

    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const validator = require("validator");
    const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const crypto = require("crypto");
    
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Enter Your Name"],
        maxLength: [30, "Name cannot exceed 30 characters"],
        minLength: [4, "Name should have more than 4 characters"],
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Enter Your Email"],
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please Enter a valid Email"],
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Enter Your Password"],
        minLength: [8, "Password should be greater than 8 characters"],
        select: false,
      },
      avatar: {
        public_id: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        url: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      role: {
        type: String,
        default: "user",
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    
      resetPasswordToken: String,
      resetPasswordExpire: Date,
    });
    
    userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
      if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        next();
      }
    
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    });

when i did try catch err call then this error was in the console log
```

error: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}

Comment: Hello could you use try catch block on code and then could you share the console error please?

Comment: Furthermore, could you share the code of user model definition?

Comment: i have added it now

Comment: Please start with your problem and not code. It would help if you could share your thoughts in the body of the question rather than in comments of the code block

Comment: when i dont use the cloudinary codes , and just insert a random avatar into the user body it works fine

Comment: so you are getting the 500 response from Cloudinary API, do you have the full response headers for the 500 error?

Comment: actually i did a console log  and found ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT erroe

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

you expected "avatar" key in body here because program trying to fetch data from req.body.avatar but in the postman request payload you didn't give avatar key in body. Probably error causes from that reason.

Comment: but i cannot register it through my website also , it shows internal 500 error . and in the above 'req.body.avatar' is for the uploaded avatar in the cloudinary.

Comment: but you expect avatar on payload -> req.body.avatar

Comment: i dont get it . can you provide the accurate soln .

Answer (score 0):

edit -
the actual error was -error: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5) at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20) at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' }

node v20.2 is not compatible with uploading on cloudinary , so i upgraded it to 20.4 and it worked.

Comment: as i understand from last sentence you need to upgrade your node version

Comment: thing is only v20.2 has issues , you can either upgrade it or downgrade it .